# Filter JSON via its array's name in same fragment using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, fragment, retrofit

I am creating a News Application using Guardian API and I want to filter data according to its pillarName (Results POJO Class) using same fragment and recyclerview in different tabs. I toyed with the idea of creating separate fragments for each tab using different API endpoints but I wanted to ask about filtering data within POJO model classes and displaying different results using the same fragment. Forgive my English as it is not my native language.

Here is the link of Guardian API: https://content.guardianapis.com/search?page-size=100&api-key=669498f5-96e3-43f6-a9b9-325e6a3c6acf&show-fields=thumbnail

Created POJO classes using JsonSchematoPOJO

**Model Classes**
JSONResponse:

```
public class JSONResponse {

@SerializedName("response")
@Expose
private Response response;

public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
}
```

Response:

```
public class Response {

@SerializedName("results")
@Expose
private List<Results> results = null;

public List<Results> getResults() {
    return results;
}
```

Results:

```
public class Results {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public String id;

@SerializedName("sectionId")
@Expose
private String sectionId;

@SerializedName("sectionName")
@Expose
private String sectionName;

@SerializedName("webTitle")
@Expose
private String webTitle;

@SerializedName("webUrl")
@Expose
private String webUrl;

@SerializedName("pillarId")
@Expose
private String pillarId;

@SerializedName("pillarName")
@Expose
private String pillarName;

@SerializedName("fields")
@Expose
private Fields fields;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSectionId() {
    return sectionId;
}

public void setSectionId(String sectionId) {
    this.sectionId = sectionId;
}

public String getSectionName() {
    return sectionName;
}

public void setSectionName(String sectionName) {
    this.sectionName = sectionName;
}

public String getWebTitle() {
    return webTitle;
}

public void setWebTitle(String webTitle) {
    this.webTitle = webTitle;
}

public String getWebUrl() {
    return webUrl;
}

public void setWebUrl(String webUrl) {
    this.webUrl = webUrl;
}

public String getPillarId() {
    return pillarId;
}

public void setPillarId(String pillarId) {
    this.pillarId = pillarId;
}

public String getPillarName() {
    return pillarName;
}

public void setPillarName(String pillarName) {
    this.pillarName = pillarName;
}

public Fields getFields() {
    return fields;
}

public void setFields(Fields fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}
```

**NewsAPI:**

public interface NewsAPI {

```
@GET("search")
Call<JSONResponse> getLatestNews(@Query("page-size") int pageSize, @Query("api-key") String apiKey,
                                 @Query("show-fields") String showFields);
```

}

**Retrofit onResponse in NewsFragment**

Code Snippet:

```
  final NewsAPI newsAPI = NewsService.getNewsService().create(NewsAPI.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = newsAPI.getLatestNews(100, API_KEY, "thumbnail");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<JSONResponse> call, @NonNull Response<JSONResponse> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                JSONResponse mJSONResponse = response.body();
                if (mJSONResponse != null || mNewsAdapter == null) {
                    mResultsList = mJSONResponse != null ? mJSONResponse.getResponse().getResults() : null;
                    mNewsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(mResultsList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNewsAdapter);
               /* } else {
                    mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }*/

                }
            }
```

I am getting a variety of news and I want to filter the result via its pillarName, my purpose was to ask that is it possible to filter it like that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assign the RecyclerViews for each tab before making the API call
- Initiate the API call and inside onResponse do something like this

  ```
  public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<JSONResponse> call, @NonNull Response<JSONResponse> response) {
      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
          JSONResponse mJSONResponse = response.body();
          if (mJSONResponse != null) {
              ArrayList<Results> resultsNews = new ArrayList<>();
              ArrayList<Results> resultsOpinion = new ArrayList<>();
              ArrayList<Results> resultsArts = new ArrayList<>();
              mResultsList = mJSONResponse.getResponse().getResults();

              for (Result result: mResultsList) {
                  if(result.pillarName.equals("news"))
                      resultsNews.add(result);
                  else if(result.pillarName.equals("opinion"))
                      resultsOpinion.add(result);
                  else if(result.pillarName.equals("arts"))
                      resultsArts.add(result);
              }

              mRecyclerViewNews.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(resultsNews);
              mRecyclerViewOpinion.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(resultsOpinion);
              mRecyclerViewArts.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(resultsArts);

         /* } else {
              mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }*/

          }
      }
  ```